# Email does not send with perl MIME::Lite using smtp

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email using MIME::Lite but the email will not send and I am not getting any errors. 
Code:

```
    my $subject = $Config->{email}->{subject};
    my $from_email = $Config->{email}->{from_email};
    my $message = $Config->{email}->{message};
    my $smtp_server = $Config->{email}->{smtp_server};
    my $msg = MIME::Lite->new
    (
    Subject => $subject,
    From    => $from_email,
    To      => $email,
    Type    => 'text/html',
    Data    => $message
    );

    $msg->send('smtp' ,$smtp_server );
```

Comment: Is sendmail installed? If yes, try sending mail with it.

Comment: [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email::Sender) has error-checking, MIME::Lite does not. - You can install [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to see the SMTProtocol talk.

Answer (score 3):

Not much to go on there ...

Maybe try debugging?

```
$msg->send( 'smtp', $smtp_server,  Debug=>1 );
```

And check all the values in `$Config->{email}` are as you would expect.

Comment: I tried the debugging with nothing new.  all of the values are correct. I am running on a VM if that's the problem. My connection is NAT and can connect to the internet.